# Get the row a table cell is part of with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the index of the cell I'm currently moused over and the index of the last cell in the row

```
$("table").delegate('td', 'mouseover mouseleave', function (e) {
            if (e.type == 'mouseover') {

                var cell_index = $(this).index(); //this works
                var last_index = $(this).parent('tr').eq(-1).index(); //returns the index of the row, not the cell
```

I've also tried

```
$(this).parent().eq(-1).index();
$(this).closest('tr').eq(-1).index();
$("table").eq($(this).parent().eq((this).index).index()).eq(-1).index();
//the last one was just for curiosity
```

None of these worked

I would like to check to see if the cell that is being moused over is the last cell. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the td collection in row to get the last td index

```
var last_index = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(-1).index();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current cell index and last cell index of parent row using below code block:

**Your code:**

```
$(function() {
    $("table").delegate('td', 'mouseover mouseleave', function (e) {
            if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
                var cell_index = $(this).index(); //this works
                var last_index = $(this).parent('tr').find('td:last-child').index();
            }
    });  
});
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7kTdE/1/

**Example code:**

```
$(function() {
    $('td').on('mouseover', function() {
        alert('Current cell index is : ' + $(this).index());
        alert('Last cell index of parent row is : ' + $(this).parent().find('td:last-child').index());
    });
});
```

Example is here : http://jsfiddle.net/7kTdE/